# Java JSONObject Distinct Key into List

Tags: java, json

Hi StackOverflow community,

I have a situation where I need to distinct the Java JSONObect key into a List. So that I can do a if else statement after that. Here is an example of my JSON Object.

```
{
  "E23": "1111",
  "E25": "5",
  "G1": {
    "b": "1",
    "c": "1"
  },
  "G2": {
    "d": "1"
  },
  "E2": "test pdf",
  "E3": "1",
  "E4": "1",
  "E5a": "12121991",
  "E6": "1",
  "E8": "7110",
  "E5b": 28,
  "E9": "01",
  "E1a": "1",
  "H3b": "4",
  "E24c1": "06",
  "E1b": "i",
  "H3a": "12",
  "E26a": [
    "04",
    "07",
    "09"
  ],
  "E14a": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "1",
    "c": "1"
  }
}
```

The end result expected is to become like this `ArrayList [E,G,H]`

Just FYI, the key.chartAt(0) can be from E-I. I am thinking to looping in each of the Object and check the character at 0 and put it in the List if the List doest contain the character yet. But I think its gonna consume a lot of java processing and my function will become longer. Is there any way that I can achieve my end result without looping through all the Object.

Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
JSONObject json = getJsonObject(); // your JSONObject
Set<String> jsonKeys = json.keySet();
Set<Character> myKeySet  = jsonKeys.stream()
            .map(key-> key.charAt(0))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(myKeySet);

Output:
[E,G,H]
```

Note: Since your keys should not be duplicated you use Set, else you can replace it with ArrayList